# Song Name database with doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm new to the site and I'm looking for some help in regards to a doubly linked list that stores Mp3's with artistname, songname, albumname, date, and running time.  If you could help me out at all, I'd appreciate it.  I have been getting a segfault according to GDB in my add function.

The warnings are also as follows:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
'data' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized] Mp3.c   /OperatingSystemsLab1   
line 7  C/C++ Problem
assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]   Mp3.c   /OperatingSystemsLab1   
line 7  C/C++ Problem
implicit declaration of function 'malloc' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] Mp3.c   /OperatingSystemsLab1   
line 21 C/C++ Problem
assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]   Mp3.c   /OperatingSystemsLab1   
line 8  C/C++ Problem
implicit declaration of function 'free' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]   Mp3.c   /OperatingSystemsLab1   
line 40 C/C++ Problem
incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]    Mp3.c   /OperatingSystemsLab1   
line 21 C/C++ Problem
incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]    Mp3.c   /OperatingSystemsLab1   
line 57 C/C++ Problem
incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [enabled by default]  Mp3.c   /OperatingSystemsLab1   
line 40 C/C++ Problem
```

My code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Mp3.h"



void add(struct MP3 *pointer, char artistname, char albumname, char songname, int date, int runtime){
    /*make structure for new data*/
struct MP3 *data;
data->artistName = artistname;
data->albumName = albumname;
data->date=date;
data->runTime=runtime;
data->next=NULL;
data->prev=NULL;

if(pointer->next==NULL) {
    pointer->next = data;
}
else {
        while(pointer->next != NULL){
        pointer = pointer->next;
    }
    pointer->next = (struct MP3*)malloc(sizeof(struct MP3));
    pointer->next = data;
    struct MP3 *temp = pointer;
    pointer = pointer->next;
    pointer->prev = temp;
}
};



void delete(struct MP3 *pointer, char *artistname){
while(pointer->next!=NULL && (pointer->next)->artistName!=artistname){
    pointer = pointer->next;
}
if(pointer->next==NULL){
    return;
}
struct MP3 *temp;
temp = pointer->next;
pointer->next = temp->next;
pointer->next->prev = pointer;
free(temp);
};



void print(struct MP3 *pointer){
if(pointer==NULL){
    return;
}
printf("Artist name: %s \n", pointer->artistName);
printf("Album name: %s \n", pointer->albumName);
printf("Title: %s \n", pointer->songName);
printf("Date: %d \n", pointer->date);
printf("Runtime: %d\n", pointer->runTime);

print(pointer->next);
};



int main(){
struct MP3 *start,*current;
start = (struct MP3 *)malloc(sizeof(struct MP3));
current = start;
current->next = NULL;
current->prev = NULL;

printf("1. Add\n");
printf("2. Delete\n");
printf("3. Print\n");
while(1)
{
    int query;
    scanf("%d",&query);
    if(query==1)
    {
        int rt,d;
        char artn,albn,sn;
        scanf("%c %c %c %d %d",&artn,&albn,&sn,&d,&rt);
        add(start,artn,albn,sn,d,rt);
    }
    else if(query==2)
    {
        char artn;
        scanf("%c",&artn);
        delete(start,&artn);
    }
    else if(query==3)
    {
        printf("The list is ");
        print(start->next);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
};
```

And the header file

```
#ifndef MP3_H_
#define MP3_H_

struct MP3{
char *artistName;
char *albumName;
char *songName;
int date;
int runTime;
struct MP3 *next;
struct MP3 *prev;

};


#endif /* MP3_H_ */
```

Like I said, I'm new so have mercy on me.  Any help at all would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem here

```
struct MP3 *data;
data->artistName = artistname;
```

you declare a pointer to `MP3` but you do not allocate memory for it. Use `malloc` to allocate the space or just use a plain instance instead.

You also have a problem here

```
 pointer->next = (struct MP3*)malloc(sizeof(struct MP3));
```

this allocates memory and sets `pointer->next` to point to it. Then in the next line

```
 pointer->next = data;
```

you reassign `pointer->next` and so that allocated memory in the previous line no longer has its address stored by any variable - the result of this is a memory leak.

Comment: So under the add I changed it to                                 struct MP3 *data;
data = malloc(sizeof(struct MP3));
data->artistName = artistname;                                          But it's still not running properly -__________-

Comment: You have changed this in ALL of the functions where you have unallocated memory?

Comment: I just also got rid of the pointer->malloc code by commenting it out.  I now get the code to actually run and print a list but let's just say it's not desirable...at all. Rofl. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @Nick You are getting segfaults or warnings? Whatever you do please DONT edit your question to add the new errors - this leads to lots and lots of confusion. If there are many many errors it may be worth opening a new question with the new updated code. Using a malloc is definitely needed in your code.

Comment: I'm not getting segfault anymore.  It's just an issue of taking in the data right now and printing out the list correctly.  I'm a lot further along than I was.

Comment: I got everything to work earlier today.  Thank you for all your help though.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

struct MP3 *data;

declares a pointer to a data structure, but it doesn't create the structure. So when you try to access it, you are accessing unallocated memory, which causes a segmentation fault.
You need to allocate the memory using malloc:

```
struct MP3 *data; /* declares a pointer to a MP3 structure */
data = malloc(sizeof(MP3)); /* creates a new MP3 structure and makes the pointer point to it */
data->artistName = artistname; /* the structure can now be used */
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says - `"'data' is uninitialized in this function"` - which is obviously true. You *declare* a *pointer to MP3 struct* called 'data'. You never *initialize* the pointer by allocating memory and initializing the pointer to point to that memory.